# How to build a formula to isolate credited amounts for Accounts Receivable Aging in Netsuite?

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm building a formula within an A/R Aging Saved Search in NetSuite. I has successfully queried for 30 Days, 60 Days, 90 Days, and > 90 Days using the following formula:

```
Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) (condition based on days) then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) (condition based on days) then {amountremaining} else 0 end
```

Our A/R team has requested that they do not want any credited amounts for > 90 days included in the total, so I wrapped the > 90 day formula with another case statement in order to exclude values less than 0. I later optimized the formula to this:

```
Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 61 and 90 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 61 and 90 then {amountremaining} else 0 end
```

A/R has requested an additional change, as they still want to isolate all credited amounts as another column on this saved search. I have tried simply switching the output of the formula above, however there are credited values on accounts that still have a net debt showing up on the query:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║    Name    ║ > 90 Days  ║ Credits in > 90 Days ║ Desireable Output ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Customer A ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer B ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer C ║ 4.95       ║ (4.95)               ║ No                ║
║ Customer D ║ 1,733.00   ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer E ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer F ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer G ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer H ║ 10,547.96  ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer I ║ 1.51       ║ (1.51)               ║ No                ║
║ Customer J ║ 0.00       ║ (21.92)              ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer K ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer L ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
║ Customer M ║ 0.00       ║ 0.00                 ║ Yes               ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

We do not want these debited accounts included for this specific column. I have tried modifying the formula multiple times but I feel that I'm missing something and I'm not sure how to progress from here.

EDIT:
I wanted to add, I have looked into individual records for the customers that show an undesirable output. There are a lot of cases for this in our system, some are from unapplied payments, credited journals, memos, etc. There are a lot of niche cases that this appears to hit. I wasn't sure if it was a good approach to try to exclude each one of those cases, as I'm not sure how many there are and how many cases would be excluded from the current dataset I am viewing. I just want to include the credited amounts from the >90 Days column and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason credited amounts weren't isolated the way I intended was because of the nature of the aforementioned formula:

```
Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) (condition based on days) then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) (condition based on days) then {amountremaining} else 0 end
```

The formula filters out negative vs positive amounts, as well as amounts between or after a certain amount of days. They doesn't take into account values that may accumulate into a 0 balance that are outside of the expected values.

To rectify this, I applied an additional summary criteria to the saved search removing entries from the results that had a Total Open Balance of 0 using this formula:

```
(Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) < 1 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) < 1 then {amountremaining} else 0 end)+ (Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 1 and 30 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 1 and 30 then {amountremaining} else 0 end) + (Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 31 and 60 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 31 and 60 then {amountremaining} else 0 end) + (Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 61 and 90 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) between 61 and 90 then {amountremaining} else 0 end) + (Case When substr({amount},1,1) = '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) > 90 then ({amountremaining}*-1) When substr({amount},1,1) <> '-' and (NVL({daysoverdue}, Round({today}-{trandate}, 0))) > 90 then {amountremaining} else 0 end)
```

This removed all accounts that had a Total Open Balance of zero or null, which should not have been included in this search in the first place.